# Operator overload error in class template due to template arguments not being constant expressions

Tags: c++, templates

I'm writing a simple matrix class that uses a template to define the datatype, as well as the number of rows and columns. However, I'm running into some issues when defining operator overloads. Here is the class so far:

```
template<typename T, size_t num_rows, size_t num_cols>
class Matrix {
    public:
        Matrix();
        Matrix(const Matrix &m); // Copy constructor
        ~Matrix();

        T operator()(const size_t row, const size_t col) const;
        T& operator()(const size_t row, const size_t col);
        Matrix& operator=(const Matrix &m); // Copy assignment operator
        Matrix operator*(const Matrix &m2) const;

    private:
        T data_[num_rows][num_cols];
        size_t num_rows_;
        size_t num_cols_;
};

template<typename T, size_t num_rows, size_t num_cols>
Matrix<T, num_rows, num_cols>::Matrix() : num_rows_(num_rows), num_cols_(num_cols) {}

template<typename T, size_t num_rows, size_t num_cols>
Matrix<T, num_rows, num_cols>::~Matrix() {}

// Copy constructor
template<typename T, size_t num_rows, size_t num_cols>
Matrix<T, num_rows, num_cols>::Matrix(const Matrix &m) :
    num_rows_(m.num_rows_),
    num_cols_(m.num_cols_)
{    
    for(size_t i = 0; i < this->num_rows_; ++i) {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < this->num_cols_; ++j) {
            (*this)(i,j) = m(i,j);
        }
    }
}

template<typename T, size_t num_rows, size_t num_cols>
T Matrix<T, num_rows, num_cols>::operator()(const size_t row, const size_t col) const {
    return data_[row][col];
}

template<typename T, size_t num_rows, size_t num_cols>
T& Matrix<T, num_rows, num_cols>::operator()(const size_t row, const size_t col) {
    return data_[row][col];
}

// Copy assignment operator
template<typename T, size_t num_rows, size_t num_cols>
Matrix<T, num_rows, num_cols>& Matrix<T, num_rows, num_cols>::operator=(const Matrix &m) {
    if(this == &m){
        return *this;
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < this->num_rows_; ++i) {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < this->num_cols_; ++j) {
            (*this)(i,j) = m(i,j);
        }
    }

    return *this;
}

// Multiplication operator overload
template<typename T, size_t num_rows, size_t num_cols>
Matrix<T, num_rows, num_cols> Matrix<T, num_rows, num_cols>::operator*(const Matrix &m2) const {

    const size_t rows = this->num_rows_;
    const size_t cols = m2.num_cols_;

    Matrix<float, rows, cols> m3;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < this->num_rows_; ++i) {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < m2.num_cols_; ++j) {
            m3(i,j) = 0.0f;
            for(size_t k = 0; k < this->num_cols_; ++k) {
                m3(i,j) += (*this)(i,k)*m2(k,j);
            }
        }
    }

    return m3;
}
```

Looking at the multiplication operator overload (please forgive the very slow matrix-matrix product implementation), the problem occurs when I try and define `Matrix<float, rows, cols> m3`. The error I get says `error: non-type template argument is not a constant expression`, which occurs because the dimensions of `m3` are dependent on the dimensions of `this` and `m2`. However, it seems that template arguments have to be known at compile time, and therefore I can't use `const size_t rows = this->num_rows_` and `const size_t cols = m2.num_cols_` when instantiating `m3`.

As such, I'm not too sure how I can get the multiplication operator overload to work (and other operator overloads that require returning a new matrix as the result of the operation), since I'm unable to create a matrix to return. Is there a way to keep the current template (i.e. datatype, rows and cols), and still get the multiplication operator overload to work?

Comment: The function's return type is `Matrix<T, num_rows, num_cols>`, not `Matrix<float, rows, cols>`. Even if you somehow managed to declare the latter, it won't do you any good - you promised to return the former. In any case, `this->num_rows_` is the same as `num_rows` and `m2.num_cols_` is the same as `num_cols`. It's unclear why you want data members that merely store a copy of template parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Make these two member variables `static constexpr` and initialize them from the template arguments, since they are just names for the template arguments there's no reason to store them in memory, they are known at compile time:

```
    size_t num_rows_;
    size_t num_cols_;
```

Also note that your copy constructor (and probably assignment operator) are pointless, the compiler would do the job for you if you didn't declare those.

Answer (score 0):

```
Matrix operator*(const Matrix &m2) const;
```

this is wrong.

```
template<std::size_t Y>
Matrix<T, num_rows,Y> operator*(const Matrix<T, num_cols, Y> &m2) const;
```

this is correct..

Also, delete

```
    size_t num_rows_;
    size_t num_cols_;
```

or make them `constexpr` or `enum` constants.

The template multiplication operator will have the 3 dimensions as part of its template arguments.

```
// Multiplication operator overload
template<typename T, size_t num_rows, size_t num_cols>
template<size_t Y>
Matrix<T, num_rows, Y> Matrix<T, num_rows, num_cols>::operator*(const Matrix<T,num_cols,Y> &m2) const {
```

you know the cols/rows of each variable from their types.